# Inserir dados de uma string numa tabela

Tags: string, lua, tabela-html

Eu tenho um arquivo de texto que eu li e ajustei ele numa string `texto` de forma que ficasse dessa forma:

```
{nome="Cassio",sexo="M",idade=19}
{nome="Paula",sexo="F",idade=20}
```

E utilizei o seguinte código para adicionar cada linha dessa  string numa posição de uma tabela:

```
dados = {} 

for linha in texto:gmatch("[^\r\n]+") do

    -- remove a quebra de linha do final da string para inserí-la na tabela
    linha = linha:gsub("\n", "")

    --insere na tabela
    table.insert(dados, linha)

end
```

O problema é que quando eu tento imprimir os dados dessa tabela, todos os dados dela aparecem como `nil`:

```
for _ in ipairs(dados) do 

    print("NOME: ", dados.nome) 
    print("SEXO: ", dados.sexo) 
    print("IDADE: ", dados.idade)
    print("\n") 

end
```

Resultado:

```
NOME:   nil
SEXO:   nil
IDADE:  nil


NOME:   nil
SEXO:   nil
IDADE:  nil
```

Como corrigir esse problema?

---

OBS: eu também tentei utilizar o seguinte código, porém o problema é o mesmo, todos os campos aparecem como `nil`:

```
filecontents = texto1
entries = {}
do
  -- define a function that our data-as-code will call with its table
  -- its job will be to simply add the table it gets to our array. 
  function entry(entrydata)
    table.insert(entries, entrydata)
  end

  -- load our data as Lua code
  thunk = load(filecontents, nil, nil, {entry = entry})
  thunk()

end
```

Nesse caso, texto1 é assim:

```
entry{nome="Cassio",sexo="M",idade=19}
entry{nome="Paula",sexo="F",idade=20}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolvendo o problema.

O melhor código para inserção dos dados, do modo que eu os recebi, na tabela, é o seguinte:

```
filecontents = texto1

entries = {}

do

  -- insere os dados do arquivo de texto na tabela

  function entry(entrydata)

      table.insert(entries, entrydata)

  end

  -- carrega os dados do arquivo na forma de código Lua

  thunk = load(filecontents, nil, nil, {entry = entry})
  thunk()

end
```

sendo o conteúdo do texto1 este:

```
entry{nome="Cassio",sexo="M",idade=19}
entry{nome="Paula",sexo="F",idade=20}
```

O modo correto de exibir os arquivos da tabela é:

```
for index, tabela in ipairs(entries) do 

    print(tabela.nome)
    ...

end
```

Dessa forma o código funciona normalmente. O `for` vai percorrer toda a tabela `entries`, a variável `tabela` vai receber o conteúdo de cada linha da tabela e utilizando essa variável você imprime os dados.

Answer (score 6):

Pelo que eu entendi, você está colocando tabelas dentro de tabelas, e para chamá-las, você precisa passar a numeração dela!

Um exemplo:

```
for i = 1, #dados do 

    print("NOME: ".. dados[i].nome) 
    print("SEXO: ".. dados[i].sexo) 
    print("IDADE: ".. dados[i].idade)
    print("\n") 

end
```

Answer (score 4):

Se você já tem o conteúdo do arquivo como string dentro de Lua e confia nesse conteúdo, então você pode usar Lua para converter tudo para você:

```
entries = load("return {"..texto:gsub("\n",",").."}")()
```